# why would my git (on windows) repositories frequently become corrupted after a commit?

Tags: windows, git

I have been using git for several years on linux with almost no issues that I did not directly cause.

Now I am working on a Windows 10 pro machine with git V2.40.1 and not having a good time.

It seems that local repositories become corrupted very easily. I think, but I am not certain, that it happens only when committing and then only with a larger number of files. The behaviour is not terribly reproducible. I have a script that does a test, copying 1000 small text files into a new repository

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p git-test
cd git-test
pwd
echo "cleaning up"
rm -rf * 2> /dev/null
rm -rf .git 2>/dev/null
touch readme.txt
git init
git add -v .
git commit -am "initial commit"
git fsck

# good so far
mkdir files
echo "copy a bunch of files.."
cp ../files/* ./files
echo "stage the files"
git add  .
git fsck
echo "commit them"
git commit -am "added  files"
echo "checking..."
git fsck
```

Now I am testing to get error messages for this question and I cannot generate an error :(

Notably, git commit is really slow in this test.

Earlier today I spent an hour trying to set up a new repository for a project with about the same number of source files. No matter how I tried, it was not possible to add the project files without generating an error. Sometimes the index became corrupt, sometimes I was left with corrupt objects. Eventually, I had to copy the files to a linux box, create the repository there, push it to a server and then clone it onto the Windows machine.

The same kinds of errors have occured in other projects - generally when a number of files have changed together - such as after a big refactor.

Next I wrote another script to modify all the files and do another commit. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd git-test
git fsck
for file in files/*.txt; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo -e "$file\r" >> "$file"
    fi
done
git fsck
git commit -am "append text to files"
git fsck
```

That generates an error all the time. One such error is:

```
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
error: corrupt loose object '90d1dc545873e8c1da89da3dad1da00d9030e398'
fatal: loose object 90d1dc545873e8c1da89da3dad1da00d9030e398 (stored in .git/objects/90/d1dc545873e8c1da89da3dad1da00d9030e398) is corrupt
[main
```

Another time I get:

```
[main bbcd556] append text to files
 1000 files changed, 2000 insertions(+)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

The same modify test with only 100 files does not generate an error.

I have told Defender to exclude the directory where my source projects live so I am assuming that it is not interference from that.

Nothing like this has ever happened on my linux machines.

I don't want to know how to fix it after the error happens - I can do that but only after a working repository exists of course. It is a royal pain to have to do as well

What I would like is some clue as to why this might happen on my windows machine and some hope that it can be prevented.

This is somewhat taking the shine off development under Windows.

Comment: Have you ruled out issues external to git, like a finicky filesystem or bad zlib implementation?

Comment: When you have some strange behavior like that, testing the memory or drive storage to see if there is an hardware issue could be a good idea...

Comment: Updating git to the last version could be a good idea too...

Comment: What file system are you using?  Are you repositories in any sort of directory that gets synced by a cloud syncing service, such as Dropbox or OneDrive?

Comment: I ran chkdsk on the filesystem and it came back clean.
The file system is ntfs and not synced by any cloud service. That said, the directories are in my home folder and Windows has an unpleasant habit of lying about what happens there. 
I should try moving it all to some directory straight unde c: perhaps.

Comment: Well, that did not help. I moved a repository to a directory under c:. cloned a fresh copy from the server, copied in the changed files from the broken one and tried a commit. 

For my trouble, I get:

fatal: unknown index entry format 0x35de0000

So that is my goto fix method shot as well.